# How to disable buttons based on which radio button is selected?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 div groups, each containing a radio button, a label, and a button.
I would like to be able to enable the button within the same group as the selected radio button, and make the buttons from other groups disabled.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- when this radio button is checked... -->
    <input id="input-1" type="radio" name="disable-button" checked="checked">
    <label for="input-1">Input 1</label>
    <!-- this button is enabled -->
    <button type="button">ADD</button>
    <!-- ...and vice versa -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- when this radio button is not checked... -->
    <input id="input-2" type="radio" name="disable-button">        
    <label for="input-2">Input 1</label>
    <!-- ...this button should be disabled -->
    <button type="button" disabled>ADD</button>
    <!-- ...and vice versa -->
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- when this radio button is not checked... -->
    <input id="input-3" type="radio" name="disable-button">
    <!-- ...this button should be disabled -->
    <label for="input-3">Input 1</label>
    <button type="button" disabled>ADD</button>
    <!-- ...and vice versa -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do this via jQuery?

edit: I would prefer the solution to be dynamic if possible in case I have to add more groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the following jQuery code:

```
$('input[type=radio]').change(function(){
  $('button').prop('disabled', true);
  $(this).parent().find('button').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dotspencer/6reL64ss/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code afterwards the parent div block.

```
 $(input[type=radio]).change(function(){
     $(this).is(':checked') && $(this).parent().find('button').prop('disabled', false) || $(this).parent().find('button').prop('disabled', true);
  });
```